# Is there a way to link a smart object to a specific single layer of the linked file?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting, smartobject

Is there a way to link a smart object to a specific single layer of the linked file?

What I want to do is this:

- have the same smart object multiplied
- each copy of the smart object to be linked to a specific layer in the linked file
- dump the images in the linked file
- adjust setting for each smart object (lighting, shadows, reflections, etc)
- and have photoshop save all smart onjects (which are nested in groups, named accordingly) through Export -> Image Assets

Thank you.

---

Edit

I have many mockups and hundreds of images organized in collections.

I want to:

- create a smart object with a "collection" (a set of approx 20 images) that needs to be inserted in the mockup
- use the mockup as a background image
- create a group around the smart object plus additional layers for settings
- make the group show only the first layer of the smart object
- duplicate the group and "relink it" to the second layer of the same smart object etc
- adjust settings for each group
- export as image assets.

Until now I:

- made the mockup
- load the set of images into the SO and scaled, moved, applied a ICC profile to the Smart Object, etc
- made visible a layer with an image from the SO
- switch to the mockup tab
- adjust settings
- export image (mockup + SO overlay)
- repeat

I don't use a script to automatically cycle through the SO layers because I need to adjust the setting for each image of the collection.

A link to the site that uses the mockups and collections [enter link description here](https://cerapixel.com/printed-glass/kitchen/countertop/marble-countertop/).

Again, thanks.

Comment: The description didn't make it any clearer to me. My head is just about ready to explode trying to figure it out. SO links to an entire file, but what you want is for the Linked SO to target a specific layer, rather than the entire file? I don't know what that would achieve... - It's further complicated by the description where you say you want to dump the images in the linked file... but if you'd target a single layer in a file, then there would be a single layer to dump, not multiple images.

Comment: I think I'd personally need images to understand it. Perhaps images of the closest you can get and a description of why it's not doing what you want (or what you'd want to happen).

Comment: Sorry about the confusion and headache. I'm working on an edit to explain better.

Comment: Not sure I fully understand the question even after the edit, it seems very complex, but a cursory glance suggests perhaps that Smart Objects might not the way to go for this kind of automation. Photoshop has [data driven graphics functionality](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/creating-data-driven-graphics.html#:~:text=%20Create%20data-driven%20graphics%20%201%20Create%20the,your%20graphics%20by%20exporting%20them%20with...%20More%20). It's a bit like mailmerge used in word processors, but for graphics. You might be better using that.

Comment: @Joonas Despite the rough description, you understood exactly what I wanted. The SO has a different ICC profile than the mockup, and I also need it for basic editing to the "dumped" images: scale, move, repeat, rotate, etc. Thanks.

Comment: @billy-kerr  Thank you for your answer. I have already looked at data-driven graphics, for the simple mockups it's perfect (I think, haven't actually used it), but for more complex mockups where the same graphic/image has to be used multiple times (for example has to be shown as a reflection), I don't know who to easily use it. I guess that the smart object would be a better variant.

Comment: I can't honestly see an easy way around your issue, but I doubt Smart Objects could be used. The problem is that you can't have different instances of the same Smart Object with different layer visibilities. As far as I know this isn't possible. You are trying to solve a problem, but using a method that can't actually be used. This is the definition of an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @billy-kerr Again, thank you. I agree with you, and besides what you said I know that I want to solve the problem in the way that I'm comfortable working, which probably could be better and less complicated.

Comment: Still a bit hazy on some of the details but would this script do? https://github.com/joonaspaakko/Batch-Mockup-Smart-Object-Replacement-photoshop-script (note: just recently got a confirmation that it [doesn't work in CS 6](https://github.com/joonaspaakko/Batch-Mockup-Smart-Object-Replacement-photoshop-script/discussions/12) right now. It's tested in CC) - nvm just saw the can't use a script line...

Comment: *Seems* to me a better workflow would be to "load files into stack".. then add your adjustments/background and export. All which would be necessary would be to toggle visibility on the layers within the "stack". I do *not* see what benefits a Smart Object offers in your described workflow. But, if you need them as SO.. simply convert each "stack" layer to an SO after loading the stack.

Comment: @Scott Thank you very much, I'll give it a go.